# Cannot GET etc with Nginx Reverse Proxy React + Node + PM2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ubuntu, nginx

In setting up an Nginx reverse proxy for both a React app and a Node web server, it seems to have broken Express on the backend, although I can tell I'm accessing it in the browser by receiving "Cannot GET XX" messages after adding the second location block soon to follow below (previously the browser was just white when visiting the API endpoints because React Router was trying to grab them).

Here's what the config looks like, where port 3000 is my React app and 4000 is my Express server, both being managed by pm2:

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
         server_name www.mywebsite.com; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

Simple Express route that won't work ("Cannot GET /"):

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello, world!');
});
```

There is some additional certbot stuff that was generated for SSL, but I'm not sure it's relevant. The React app works perfectly, but whether it's "location /api/" vs "location /api" and no matter how I name my routes in Express, they all can't resolve despite having worked perfectly before. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

EDIT: I changed the server conf to at least map /api/ to my server's root with a trailing backslash so I don't have to prepend /api to every route handler, but the issue still remains ("Cannot GET /").

Comment: Can you include some of the nginx log entries?

Comment: There are unfortunately no errors or anomalous entries in the access.log, which makes me think maybe it's just a weird issue with Express? It outputs "Cannot GET /api/" when visiting the site, which is what Express seems to output when it works but just has a routing issue.

Comment: Just updated a little bit; added a backslash to the proxy_pass and included just the simplest route that's returning "Cannot GET /" when behind nginx. Can get it to work by not running nginx, so that at least narrows it down.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the following headers?

```
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
```

Probably not needed if you are using TLS/https and it may be causing issues with express if the upgrade header exists. Try removing that.

These headers are generally used for WebSockets. See [the nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) for more details.

Comment: Grabbed them from various tutorials for setting up nginx... doesn't help though unfortunately :/ Still "Cannot GET /" when visiting mywebsite.com/api/, with the above-written route.